# Get all checked checkboxes in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, scope

I am new in angular js. 
MY Template:

```
<div class="inputField">
    <h1>Categories</h1>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="all" ng-model="all" ng-change="checkAll();" ng-true-value="1">All Cuisines</label>
        <label ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="all"  ng-model="filter.cats[category.id]" ng-change="SingleCheck(category.id);" value="category.id">{{category.category_name}}
        </label>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fRight greenBtn" ng-click="ApplyFilter();">Apply</a>
```

Controller:

```
App.controller("FilterRestCtrl",function($scope,basic,stateList){
   // stateList.autoFill();
    var home_data = {
        requestFor: "cate_states"
    }
    $scope.filter = {
        cats: []
    };
    basic.hitAPI(basic.defaultVal.sitePath + "getCategoryAndStates", {reqObject: JSON.stringify(home_data)}).success(function (response) {
        if (response.type == "success") {
            $scope.imagePath = basic.defaultVal.imagePath;
            $scope.home_data = response;
            $scope.categories= response.all_categories;
        }else if (response.type == "error") {
            basic.messages.showErrorMessage(response.message);
        }else {
            basic.messages.showErrorMessage("Oops... Something went wrong .. please try again");
        }
    });
    $scope.checkAll = function() {
        if($scope.all == 1){
            $scope.filter.cats = $scope.categories.map(function(item){ return item.id;});
        }else{
            $scope.filter.cats = [];
        }
    };
    $scope.ApplyFilter = function() {
        console.log($scope.filter.cats);
    };
    $scope.SingleCheck = function($cat){
        $scope.filter.cats.push($cat);
    }

});
```

First of all. i want to checked all checkboxes all click on the first checkbox. It work fine work after this check when i click on Apply then it return an empty array. but i want to checked values.
If i click on checkboes and then click on apply then it works fine. then why it not working on all selected checkboxes. i wanr result like this:

```
["48", "34", "50", "33", "35", "47", "36", "45", "49", "46", "44", "43", "42", "31", "37", "41", "38"]
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `checkAll` function as given below.you got an empty array somehow because `if($scope.all == 1)` this was not evaluating to `true`.

```
$scope.checkAll = function() {
    if($scope.all){
                  $scope.filter.cats = $scope.categories.map(function(item){ return item.id;});
    }else{
          $scope.filter.cats = [];
    }
  console.log( $scope.filter.cats) //verify this log if its populated correctly
};
```

if this is not working check the value of `$scope.all` inside your `checkAll` function

Comment: Its working fine.. but when i click on any perticular checkbox.. then everything will be mashup.